# Laravel relationships multitables

Tags: laravel

I have a data base like this :

**For invoices:**

- ID
- Amount
- Person_iD (In relation with persons table)
- Subaccount_ID (In relation with subcaccount table)

**For persons:**

- ID
- Person_name
- Position_ID (in relation with table positions)

I need to display for each INVOICE

- ID
- Amount
- Person_Name ( where in in person table)
- Subaccount_name (Where is in person table)
- Position_name (Where is in table positions but the foreign key is in person table)

Any documentation about this example please ? 
My relations

**In Model Person :** (relation with invoices / person_id)

```
 public function userinvoice() {
return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class, 'person_id');
}
```

**In Subaccount model :** (relation with invoices / Subaccount_id)

```
public function subaccountinvoice() {
return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class, 'subaccount_id');
}
```

**In Position Model :**  (relation with persons / position_id)

```
 public function pos() {
return $this->hasMany(Person::class, 'position_id');
}
```

Comment: Seems like standard belongsTo relationships, what's the problem?  Read the docs and return if you come up with a specific question.

Comment: Hello sir, i tried but i failed, i'm looking for another documentation.. please check out my eddited post if it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have set up relationships correctly:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['persons' => function($query){
                 $query->with('position')->get()
             }])->with('subaccount')->get();
```

person name:

```
$invoice->person->name
```

sub account name:

```
$invoice->subaccount->name
```

position name:

```
$invoice->person->position->name
```

Comment: Hello sir. Isn't working for me, maybe a i have an error in relationships, can you check my eddited post please ?

Comment: invoice model has the relationship keys. you didn't included your invoice model.

Comment: I didnt write something in invoice model, what i need to write on it ?